# pyGTK subclassing issue. Double self passing to the method

Tags: python, pygtk, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass gtk.DrawingArea.
Here's the problem part of the code.

```
class ClusterGraph(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClusterGraph, self).__init__()
        self.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_mouse_dn)

    def on_mouse_dn(*args):
        print args

window = gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.set_default_size(300, 600)
cg = ClusterGraph()
window.add(cg)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

The problem is that the instance is passed to the method twice.

on click it prints:

```
(<ClusterGraph object at 0x30167d8 (GtkDrawingArea at 0x2531610)>, <ClusterGraph object at 0x30167d8 (GtkDrawingArea at 0x2531610)>, <gtk.gdk.Event at 02F75F08: GDK_BUTTON_PRESS x=164,00, y=354,00, button=1>)
```

and my callback actually is equivalent for

```
def on_mouse_dn(self, self, event)
```

How to solve this problem? Or is it normal!?

by the way, why it prints

```
<ClusterGraph object at 0x30167d8 (GtkDrawingArea at 0x2531610)>
```

and not something like

```
<ClusterGraph object at 0x30167d8 (ClusterGraph at 0x2531610)>
```

**Edit:** The question is how to remove the extra argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved in such way..

GTK invokes callback in this way: `cb(widget,event)` where widget is instance of some widget class. So I needed explicit instance referense. This can be achieved by executing method from class obj.

```
self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_mouse_dn)
```

shall be replaced with

```
self.connect('button-press-event', self.__class__.on_mouse_dn)
```

or

```
self.connect('button-press-event', ClusterGraph.on_mouse_dn)
```

The first form is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

When defining your method, you don't include self, so when called, args will include self and the other arguments.

Since it's a pygtk event handler, it's definition should look like:

```
   57   def button_press_event(widget, event):
   58       if event.button == 1 and pixmap != None:
   59           draw_brush(widget, event.x, event.y)
   60       return True
```

(from [pygtk tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-EventHandling.html))

So, the arguments passed will be widget and event. In total, because you're in a class you'll have these arguments `(self, widget, event)`

Since you're doing `self.connect`, this means `widget` will evaluate to `self`. So, you get the illusion that the arguments are `(self, self, event)`.

Either use `def on_mouse_dn(self, widget, event):` or `def on_mouse_dn(self, *args):`. The first one seems most meaningful...

**UPDATE**: To not pass `widget` as an argument, you would have to use a lambda like `self.connect('button-press-event', lambda w, e: self.on_mouse_dn(e))`. And just use `def on_mouse_dn(self, event):`. It might not be a good idea though (not sure), in case your code ever changes...

Comment: Yes, I understand, that args are `self`, `widget` and `event`. But `self is widget`, so I dont need it (no matter what it is called) twice. I could use `@staticmethod` definition to "exclude" `self`. But in fact it is not a static method, so I think that it is not right solution. Are there other options?

Comment: Ok. It seems from your question that you didn't know where the "second" self came from. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for inaccuracy in the question (English is not my native language). I think that spawn lambda-wrappers is not entirely correct. Especially if I define a lot of methods. It seems there is more elegant solution.

Comment: @akaRem Sorry, can't think of another solution.

Comment: You can also use [`connect_object`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--connect-object)